# esp-idf first partition offset

Tags: esp32, esp-idf

As far as I understand, the partition table is flashed at 0x8000, and it's size is 0xC00.
So the first partition should be able to start at offset 0x8C00, but in reality only 0x9000 is allowed. Why?

```
  CSV Error: First partition offset 0x8100 overlaps end of partition table 0x9000
```

I have not changed the bootloader, nor the partition table offset.

Comment: What value has `CONFIG_PARTITION_TABLE_OFFSET` in your `sdkconfig`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue is that the partition table needs to be an entire flash sector:  https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/issues/9846#issuecomment-1257178079

> The error message is misleading here, the actual reason why the partition can't start at 0x8c00 is that we don't support partitions which aren't aligned to SPI Flash erase sector size (0x1000).
> We'll take a look at the tool and make changes so that the correct error is reported.